# Find cells crossed by a line

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, collision

This method find cells that are crossed by line A-B and adds them to one vector.
I have got some duplicates here and some lines of code are very similiar but they differ in one variable. Should this duplicated be fixed or is it fine?

```
std::vector<Cell> Grid::findCells(int xA,int yA,  int xB,  int yB) {

vector<Cell> setOfCellsToUnmark;
//
int xI, yI, t;

if (xA < xB) {
    for (xI = coordinateToCellIndex(xA) * SIZE_CONST + MOVEMENT;
         xI < xB; xI += SIZE_CONST) { 
        t = (xI - xA) / (xB - xA);
        yI = yA + t * (yB - yA);
        //find coordinates that X axis is crossed by line from xA to xB inclusive
        addToVector(xI, yI, setOfCellsToUnmark);
        //find coordinates that X axis is crossed by line from xA to xB exclusive
        addToVector(xI + MOVEMENT, yI, setOfCellsToUnmark);
    }
}
else {
    for (xI = coordinateToCellIndex(xA) * SIZE_CONST - MOVEMENT;
         xI > xB; xI -= SIZE_CONST) { 
        t = (xI - xA) / (xB - xA);
        yI = yA + t * (yB - yA);
        addToVector(xI, yI, setOfCellsToUnmark);
        addToVector(xI + MOVEMENT, yI, setOfCellsToUnmark);
    }
}

if (yA < yB) {
    for (yI = coordinateToCellIndex(yA) * SIZE_CONST + MOVEMENT;
         yI < yB; yI += SIZE_CONST) { 
        t = (yI - yA) / (yB - yA);
        xI = xA + t * (xB - xA);
        addToVector(xI, yI, setOfCellsToUnmark);
        addToVector(xI, yI + MOVEMENT, setOfCellsToUnmark);
    }
} else {
    for (yI = coordinateToCellIndex(yA) * SIZE_CONST - MOVEMENT;
         yI > yB; yI -= SIZE_CONST) { 
        t = (yI - yA) / (yB - yA);
        xI = xA + t * (xB - xA);
        addToVector(xI, yI, setOfCellsToUnmark);
        addToVector(xI, yI + MOVEMENT, setOfCellsToUnmark);
    }
}
return setOfCellsToUnmark;
}


void Grid::addToVector(const int x, const int y, vector<Cell> & setOfCells) const {
    Cell c = coordinateToCellIndex(x, y);
    if (isCellInGrid(c)) {
        setOfCells.push_back(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're implementing is called [Bresenham's Line Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).

You can get rid of the duplication by implementing the algorithm as described on wikipedia. Mirrored here for completeness:

```
 function line(x0, y0, x1, y1)
     real deltax := x1 - x0
     real deltay := y1 - y0
     real error := 0
     real deltaerr := abs(deltay / deltax)    // Assume deltax != 0 (line is not vertical),
           // note that this division needs to be done in a way that preserves the fractional part
     int y := y0
     for x from x0 to x1
         plot(x,y)
         error := error + deltaerr
         while error ≥ 0.5 then
             plot(x, y)
             y := y + sign(y1 - y0)
             error := error - 1.0
```

If you want to, you can also look at my implementation [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/93407/bresenham-line-drawing-implementation).